# Convert a semidefinite program from CVX to CVXPY

Tags: python, matlab, convex-optimization, cvx, cvxpy

I want to convert the following SDP — which just verifies the feasibility of the constraints — from CVX (MATLAB) to CVXPY (Python):

```
Ah = [1.0058, -0.0058; 1, 0];
Bh = [-1; 0];
Ch = [1.0058, -0.0058; -0.9829, 0.0056];
Dh = [-1; 1];

M = [0, 1;1, 0];
ni = size(M,1)/2;
n = size(Ah,1);
rho = 0.5;

cvx_begin sdp quiet
    variable P(n,n) semidefinite
    variable lambda(ni) nonnegative
    Mblk = M*kron(diag(lambda),eye(2));
    lambda(ni) == 1  % break homogeneity (many ways to do this...)
    [Ah Bh]'*P*[Ah Bh] - rho^2*blkdiag(P,0) + [Ch Dh]'*Mblk*[Ch Dh] <= 0
cvx_end


switch cvx_status
    case 'Solved'
        feas = 1;
    otherwise
        feas = 0;
end
```

Below is my Python code,

```
import cvxpy as cvx
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp


Ah = np.array([[1.0058, -0.0058], [1, 0]])
Bh = np.array([[-1], [0]])
Ch = np.array([[1.0058, -0.0058], [-0.9829, 0.0056]])
Dh = np.array([[-1], [1]])

M = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]])
ni, n = M.shape[0] / 2, Ah.shape[0]
rho = 0.5

P = cvx.Semidef(n)
lamda = cvx.Variable()

Mblk = np.dot(M, np.kron(cvx.diag(lamda), np.eye(2)))
ABh = np.concatenate((Ah, Bh), axis=1)
CDh = np.concatenate((Ch, Dh), axis=1)
constraints = [lamda[-1] == 1,
               np.dot(ABh.T, np.dot(P, ABh)) - rho**2*np.linalg.block_diag(P, 0) +
               np.dot(CDh.T, np.dot(Mblk, CDh)) << 0]

prob = cvx.Problem(cvx.Minimize(1), constraints)
feas = prob.status is cvx.OPTIMAL
```

There are several errors when I run the program.
1. When I print Mblk, it shows

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
>   line 2820, in run_code
>
> Out[1]:     exec code_obj in self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> Mblk
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/displayhook.py",
>   line 247, in **call**
>
> format_dict, md_dict = self.compute_format_data(result)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/displayhook.py",
>   line 157, in compute_format_data
>
> return self.shell.display_formatter.format(result)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py",
>   line 152, in format
>
> data = formatter(obj)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py",
>   line 481, in **call**
>
> printer.pretty(obj)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py", line
>   362, in pretty
>
> return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py", line
>   482, in _default_pprint
>
> p.text(repr(obj))
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line
>   1553, in array_repr
>
> ', ', "array(")
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/arrayprint.py", line
>   454, in array2string
>
> separator, prefix, formatter=formatter)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/arrayprint.py", line
>   256, in _array2string
>
> 'int' : IntegerFormat(data),
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/arrayprint.py", line
>   641, in **init**
>
> max_str_len = max(len(str(maximum.reduce(data))),
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cvxpy/constraints/leq_constraint.py",
>   line 67, in **nonzero**
>
> Raise Exception("Cannot evaluate the truth value of a constraint.")
>
> Exception: Cannot evaluate the truth value of a constraint.

When I step to this line,

```
  constraints = [lamda[-1] == 1,
                   np.dot(ABh.T, np.dot(P, ABh)) - rho**2*np.linalg.block_diag(P, 0) +
                   np.dot(CDh.T, np.dot(Mblk, CDh)) << 0]
```

it shows

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>
> ".../sdp.py", line 22, in
>
> ```
> np.dot(ABh.T, np.dot(P, ABh)) - rho**2*np.linalg.block_diag(P, 0) +
> ```
>
> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

How to fix these problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The big issue with your code is that you can't use NumPy functions on CVXPY objects. You need to use the equivalent CVXPY functions. Here's a working version of your code:

```
import cvxpy as cvx
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp


Ah = np.array([[1.0058, -0.0058], [1, 0]])
Bh = np.array([[-1], [0]])
Ch = np.array([[1.0058, -0.0058], [-0.9829, 0.0056]])
Dh = np.array([[-1], [1]])

M = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]])
ni, n = M.shape[0] / 2, Ah.shape[0]
rho = 0.5

P = cvx.Semidef(n)
lamda = cvx.Variable()

Mblk = M*lamda*np.eye(2)
ABh = cvx.hstack(Ah, Bh)
CDh = cvx.hstack(Ch, Dh)
zeros = np.zeros((n,1))
constraints = [lamda[-1] == 1,
               ABh.T*P*ABh - rho**2*cvx.bmat([[P,zeros],[zeros.T, 0]]) +
               CDh.T*Mblk*CDh << 0]

prob = cvx.Problem(cvx.Minimize(1), constraints)
prob.solve()
feas = prob.status is cvx.OPTIMAL
```

I removed the kron function because it wasn't doing anything here and CVXPY doesn't currently support Kronecker products with a variable left-hand side. I can add it if you need it.

Comment: I see one example in the [tutorial] (http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/tutorial/intro/index.html#vectors-and-matrices) uses numpy in the object function.

Comment: I may expand `lamda` to a vector. That is the reason why I need `kron`.