# Setting a constraint on the partial transpose of a variable matrix in CVXPY

Tags: python, matrix, solver, sdp, cvxpy

I'm calculating an SDP problem in Python using CVXPY and I want to set the constraint that not only my variable matrix is positive semidefinite (psd) but also its partial transpose over a certain axis is psd. I don't know how to set this requirement. My code would look as follows

```
#Set the variable matrix
P_0 = cp.Variable((d,d), symmetric=True)
```

Now i would like to define something like

```
def PT(d1, d2, rho):
    """Return rho^{T_1}, the partial trace of the density operator rho on C^{d_1} \ot C^{d_2} along the first system."""
    assert rho.shape == (d1 * d2, d1 * d2)

    # reshape into a 4-tensor (2 ket indices and 2 bra indices)
    rho = rho.reshape(d1, d2, d1, d2)

    # transpose the first subsystem
    rho = rho.transpose((0,3,2,1))

    # reshape back into a density operator
    return rho.reshape(d1 * d2, d1 * d2)
```

And then set the requirement that `PT(3,3, P_0) >> 0` i.e. that it is psd. But this is not allowed in cvxpy. Also I could define a new matrix for my specific case like

```
P_0_tp = [[P_0[[0,0]], P_0[[1, 0]], P_0[[2, 0]], P_0[[0, 3]], P_0[[1, 3]], P_0[[2, 3]], 
  P_0[[0, 6]], P_0[[1, 6]], P_0[[2, 6]]], [P_0[[0, 1]], P_0[[1, 1]], P_0[[2, 1]], 
  P_0[[0, 4]], P_0[[1, 4]], P_0[[2, 4]], P_0[[0, 7]], P_0[[1, 7]], 
  P_0[[2, 7]]], [P_0[[0, 2]], P_0[[1, 2]], P_0[[2, 2]], P_0[[0, 5]], P_0[[1, 5]], 
  P_0[[2, 5]], P_0[[0, 8]], P_0[[1, 8]], P_0[[2, 8]]], [P_0[[3, 0]], P_0[[4, 0]], 
  P_0[[5, 0]], P_0[[3, 3]], P_0[[4, 3]], P_0[[5, 3]], P_0[[3, 6]], P_0[[4, 6]], 
  P_0[[5, 6]]], [P_0[[3, 1]], P_0[[4, 1]], P_0[[5, 1]], P_0[[3, 4]], P_0[[4, 4]], 
  P_0[[5, 4]], P_0[[3, 7]], P_0[[4, 7]], P_0[[5, 7]]], [P_0[[3, 2]], P_0[[4, 2]], 
  P_0[[5, 2]], P_0[[3, 5]], P_0[[4, 5]], P_0[[5, 5]], P_0[[3, 8]], P_0[[4, 8]], 
  P_0[[5, 8]]], [P_0[[6, 0]], P_0[[7, 0]], P_0[[8, 0]], P_0[[6, 3]], P_0[[7, 3]], 
  P_0[[8, 3]], P_0[[6, 6]], P_0[[7, 6]], P_0[[8, 6]]], [P_0[[6, 1]], P_0[[7, 1]], 
  P_0[[8, 1]], P_0[[6, 4]], P_0[[7, 4]], P_0[[8, 4]], P_0[[6, 7]], P_0[[7, 7]], 
  P_0[[8, 7]]], [P_0[[6, 2]], P_0[[7, 2]], P_0[[8, 2]], P_0[[6, 5]], P_0[[7, 5]], 
  P_0[[8, 5]], P_0[[6, 8]], P_0[[7, 8]], P_0[[8, 8]]]]
```

which is a 9x9 matrix that is now partially transposed in the second 3rd dimension. But how can I set this to be a variable in cvxpy?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem as you today: I wanted to create a new matrix that consisted of combinations of variables I had defined previously. I found an answer to my question in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755392/convert-a-semidefinite-program-from-cvx-to-cvxpy). The problem with your second approach, the array `P_0_tp`, is that it is not made using cvxpy operations. You can construct it using for example `cvxpy.vstack` and `cvxpy.hstack`, or other available functions as you can find [here](https://www.cvxpy.org/api_reference/cvxpy.atoms.affine.html#matmul) (it seems there is a `reshape` function too...).

In the question I pose [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60430844/correct-way-to-impose-psd-constraint-on-a-matrix-consisting-of-expressions-in-cv), you can see how I ended up implementing it. I copy it here for completeness:

```
import cvxpy as cp

X = cp.Variable((3,3), PSD=True)

row_1 = cp.hstack((0, 1, X[0,0]))
row_2 = cp.hstack((1, 0, X[1,2]))
row_3 = cp.hstack((X[0,0], X[1,2], 0))

W = cp.vstack((row_1, row_2, row_3))
constraint = [W >> 0]
```

As you can see, I did not define W to be a variable, but now it is a cvxpy object:

```
In [1] W
Out[1]: Expression(AFFINE, UNKNOWN, (3, 3))
```

Comment: Nice, it seems that this does what I want to do. The `reshape` function does exist but it doesn't allow for objects with higher dimension than 2 (i.e. tensors). So you cannot use it for the partial trace.

Comment: If you think it works, could you accept my answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

This might come out a little bit late, but CVXPY now allows for a `partial_transpose`. Based on the axis you want to transpose, you could do:

`P_0_tb = cp.partial_transpose(P_0, dims=[3,3], axis=1)`

and then add the constraint in the new matrix:

`constraint = [P_0_tb >> 0]`